# Zsh is saying I have an unmatched ' in my shell script. Where is it?

Tags: mysql, macos, shell, zsh

I'm getting an error on line 7 that I have an unmatched ' in my zsh shell script, but I don't see it. What am I missing?

```
#!/bin/zsh

for f in csvs/*.csv
do
    mytable=$(basename "$f" .csv)
    mysql -e "load data local infile '"$f"' into table '"$mytable"' fields TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ignore 1 rows"  -u root --password=password --local-infile
done
```

Comment: You're not escaping the double quotes in your string.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen That's strange, I copied the syntax from somewhere else. Wrapping the double quotes in single quotes doesn't get it done then?

Comment: It does, but you're not doing that either. `"foo'bar'baz"` has no single quoting, only literal apostrophes in a double quoted string.

Comment: @ian-campbell: Some of your single quotes (for instance the one just before `"$f"`) are inside a double-quoted string and hence don't count. The first single quote which is actually taken into account, is the one just in front of ` LINES`. Counting from there, I have 3 single quotes in total, which explains the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put quotes inside quotes in shell, they become literal characters. So any use of the quotes terminates the quoted string.

```
mysql -e "load data local infile '"$f"' into table '"$mytable"' fields ...
         ^start                end^  ^start      end^        ^start...
```

The single-quotes inside are just characters. They don't escape the double-quote that follows. It's as if you did this:

```
mysql -e "load data local infile _"$f"_ into table _"$mytable"_ fields ...
```

In fact, you don't need to terminate the double-quotes to get shell variables into that string.

```
$ foo=string
$ echo "foo is '$foo'"
foo is 'string'
```

Now the source of your error is because you had a case where you need a literal `"` character in your SQL statement:

```
...ENCLOSED BY '"'...
             end^
```

Again, the single-quotes don't do anything to escape this. So the shell thinks it's a termination of your whole double-quoted string. Then it is followed by a `'` character that is now *outside* the double-quoted string, so this one *does* have special meaning to the shell. That is the unmatched `'` in your error.

You should also escape the backslash in `'\n'` so MySQL sees the `\n`.

In the comments below, we also remembered that the table name must not be in single-quotes.

So the fix is:

```
mysql -e "load data local infile '$f' into table $mytable fields TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' ignore 1 rows"  -u root--password=password --local-infile
```

Comment: Thank you. However now mysql is giving me the following syntax error: `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''B99283' fields TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' igno' at line 1`

Comment: I got rid of the syntax error by removing the single quotes around `$mytable` but the script does not add any data to the database. However since that's outside the scope of this question I will accept your answer.

Comment: Oh yes, I was focused on the shell quoting issue and I didn't examine the LOAD DATA statement. Single-quotes are for strings, not table names.

Comment: I got the script to work but had to remove one of those 3 backslashes in the `\\\n`

Comment: Great, I have edited my answer above, so future readers will see the correct answer.